# Titanium 3.0 Remove Webview Drop Shadows

Tags: webview, titanium, appcelerator, shadow

In titanium 3.0 I'm not able to completely remove the overscroll drop shadows a webview has on iOS. I don't want to disable scrolling at all and I like the bounce effect, I just want the shadows gone.

I've tried the 1.8.2 SDK hack but that didn't work.

I've put them in a scrollview and that partially works, and by that I mean a newly created webview has it's shadow removed, but when navigating back to a previous webview the shadow returns.

Anyone know a definitive way to solve this? I've searched for ages and found absolutely no fully working solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how possible this is, could you provide a link to the "1.8.2 SDK hack" you are talking about? Or code you've already tried?

Comment: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/118810/how-to-disable-scrolling-and-shadows-in-a-webview

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var scroll = Ti.UI.createScrollView();
var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    url : "http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html",
    disableBounce : true,
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE
});
scroll.add(webView);
window.add(scroll);
window.open();
```

This just makes the web view the size of its content, and puts it in a scrollview, the scrollview still gives the bounce that you like, without the drop shadow.

I'm not sure I know what you mean by "navigating back to a previous webview the shadow returns" but this method works for me. Sometimes it requires some JavaScript eval injection to fix margins and remove scroll, but otherwise it's good.